# Error when reconnecting with UDP protocol in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, datagram

I am creating an application which has to receive compressed video stream via Wi-Fi with UDP protocol. The source of video stream is DIY project with ARM microcontroller and WLAN module. I have a problem when try to reconnect. When first time I set learnObject var to true everything is all right. But there is an error when I close that connection calling closeUdpSocket() and then try to connect one more time. Error is: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThowAfterRecvForm(IoBridge.java:551). How do You think what can be wrong with it?
Thank You for help

```
    public CameraView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();

        // Create Bitmap for video frame
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888/*Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8*//*Bitmap.Config.RGB_565*/);
        screenRect = new Rect(0, 0, 680, 510);

        // Create and set paint color and its transparency
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
//      paint.setARGB(100, 255, 0, 0);

        // Prepare for drawing Rects
        outerRect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        innerRect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

        Log.d("S3", "stworzono bitmape");
    }

    public void onResumeCameraView() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void onPauseCameraView() {
        boolean retry = true;
        running = false;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        int blobx = MainActivity.blobx, bloby = MainActivity.bloby, blobw = MainActivity.blobw, blobh = MainActivity.blobh;
        Canvas canvas;
        int len = 0, n, j;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (running) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (!/*isSurfaceCreated*/surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (MainActivity.wlanStatus == 1)
                Log.d("S3", "wlan activ");
            else if (MainActivity.wlanStatus == 2)
                Log.d("S3", "wlan deactivated");
            else if (MainActivity.wlanStatus == 3)
                Log.d("S3", "wlan error occured");

//          canvas = null;
            // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
            // in the surface
//          try {

                // Create Canvas and set white background color
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
//              synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    canvas.drawColor(0xFF5C5C5C);

                    if (MainActivity.learnObject == false && MainActivity.wlanStatus == MainActivity.WLAN_STATUS_DEINITIALIZED) {
                        MainActivity.wlanStatus = MainActivity.WLAN_STATUS_OFF;
                        closeUdpSocket();
                        Log.d("S3", "Socket zamkniety");
                    }
                    if (MainActivity.learnObject == true && MainActivity.wlanStatus == MainActivity.WLAN_STATUS_INITIALIZED) {
                        MainActivity.wlanStatus = MainActivity.WLAN_STATUS_RUNNING;
                        createUdpSocket();
                        Log.d("S3", "Socket utworzony");
                    }

                    if (MainActivity.learnObject && (MainActivity.wlanStatus == MainActivity.WLAN_STATUS_RUNNING)) {
                        buffer.rewind();
                        try {
                            sock.send(header);

                            if (D)
                                Log.d(TAG,"Start of receiving jpeg.");

                            len = 0;
                            j = 0;
                            do {
                                sock.receive(packet);
                                n = packet.getLength();
                                buffer.put(packet.getData(), 0, n);

                                if (D) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Read: " + n + " bytes");
                                    ++j;
                                }

                                len += n;
        //                      packet.setLength(1024);
                            } while (n == 1024);
                            if (D)
                                Log.d(TAG, "End of receiving jpeg, received: " + j + " packets");

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        buffer.rewind();

                            if(frameData == null) { // do it only once at the beginning
                                frameData = new byte[IMAGE_SIZE];

                                if(D)
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Memory allocated for frameData: " + IMAGE_SIZE);

                            }

                            buffer.get(frameData, 0, len);  // copy data from main buffer into temporary frameData buffer
                        try {   
                            retval = pixeltobmp(frameData, len, bitmap);    // for mjpeg decoding we can use this external jpeg library
        //                  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData, 0, len));   // or this Java built-in library 
        //                  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(frameData, 0, len);  // or this Java built-in library 

                            if ((bitmap != null) && (retval == 0)) {    // check if new bitmap is available
                                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, screenRect, paint);
                            } else {
                                if (D)
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Error: Can't decode the incoming data");
                            }

                            freeCameraMemory();
                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                    }
//              }
//          } finally {
//             // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
//             // an inconsistent state
//             if (canvas != null) {
//                 surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
//             }
//          }   // end finally

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

//          SystemClock.sleep(10000);

            sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            try {
                   if (sleepTime > 0) {
                          Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                   }
                   else {
                          Thread.sleep(10);
                   }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    private void createUdpSocket()
    {
        try {
            sock = new DatagramSocket();
            sock.setSoTimeout(500); // 10000
            header = new DatagramPacket("HEADER".getBytes(), 6, InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_ADDR), SERVER_PORT);
            packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: Can't create Socket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: Invalid Host IP Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    private void closeUdpSocket()
    {
        if (sock != null)
            sock.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? May be it is not ready to communicate to the new socket just yet, may be it still servicing old (now closed on your side) socket and just doesn't reply back within timeframe?

Comment: I noticed that when after first successful connect I will disconnect, shutdown the application and remove it from last opened application list and then run it again, I can connect to the host successfully. When I don't remove it from last opened application list I can't connect. It returns an error Socket timeout. What wrong with this code?